# From my XYZ Server's IP to my Yahoo Domain - htaccess settings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello there and I apologize if this has been posted already.
I would need some help, I am a novice as you can see.

Here is the Issue:
The web site has been finished and needs now to go "live".
My current website is on a xyz cloud server with the IP 65.61.xxx.xx, which when entered in the browser shows my site correctly etc.
Now I need to change the IP address to the domain name which is hosted via Yahoo.

As been instructed, I would need to create a re-write rule in the htaccess (in the main root folder?), is the below correct and can this be applied to an IP address as the HTTP_host too?
Besides the above change do I need to change any other setting on my server or anywhere else?

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 65.61.xxx.xx.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newyahoodomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

If I only enter the newyahoodomain.com/ in the web browser it shows "It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

Sorry for this question, and I appreciate your reply! 
Thanks, Steve

Comment: Please provide apache host configuration that you used. The whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see "It works!", but not the site, then it is possible that your host definition in apache missing `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives. They tell to Apache to use this configuration when the request of specified domain name comes to your server. E.G:

```
ServerName http://www.newyahoodomain.com/
```

Check out this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you and let me try this in the htaccess file. Will revert back. thanks again

Comment: where do I enter this line in the htaccess file? Thanks

Comment: @SteveF. You need to enter it in your host configuration, not in htaccess file. Host configuration file location varies depending on which OS you run apache on. If it is Debian based then search for it in /etc/apache2/sites-available if it is CentOS then /etc/httpd/sites-available. In general - `read documentation about "Virtual Host" in apache docs, it will provide a lot of information for you`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks and I have read the documentation several time and also the official ubuntu HTTPD Apache2 Web Server doc. Now I have entered the "ServerName" and "ServerAlias" in "/etc/apache2/sites-available", I can also successfully restart Apache with "service apache2 restart", the browser still shows only "It works". For the DocumentRoot I have "/var/www", my Magento install is in there, or should it be "/var/www/magento"?

Comment: @SteveF. `in "/etc/apache2/sites-available"` it is a directory. inside you can find files called default and default-ssl. First one is enabled already, second one is disabled by default. first contains configuration for standard protocol, second for HTTPS access. They both point to `/var/www/index.html` as a default file. You perhaps also need to remove reference to that file. But better if you here just post content of all files inside `sites-available`, then we would be able to narrow down possible reasons why it doesn't work. Now I am just shooting blind.

Comment: Hi Alex. Correct it pointed to /var/www only. I only changed the default file and left the default -ssl file alone. when i changed it to /var/www/magento, the website started to apear but broken, so i gave this task to my webdesign team to figure it out since they degned the site ;-) all for good now and thank you for your help. at least i know now where to look for the files in the future. Cheers